# User Principal in JAAS Login Module - extra attributes as separate Principal or as Bean properties?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, tomcat, jaas

I've implemented a JAAS `LoginModule` that is working great with Spring 4 and Struts 2.3. This same `LoginModule` is also invoked via a `ServletFilter` in Tomcat 8.0/8.5 to authenticate and authorize requests to Servlets outside of the Spring framework.

The `LoginModule` uses a simple implementation of `java.security.acl.Group` and separates the User(s) and Role(s) with two simple implementations of `java.security.Principal`. By "simple" I mean the minimal implementations that satisfy the interfaces.

The "User" implementation maps the `name` property to a unique username (actually an e-mail address). Since the e-mail address is unique but could change, the account database contains a unique account identifier (GUID) that is used to assign groups, roles and to log service requests (while also anonymizing our users). In my model, the `AccountIdentifier` has its own class. Essentially, I have two unique identifiers for accounts, but since the e-mail address needs to be supplied to the `LoginModule` for authentication, it ended up being the basis for the User principal.

The account identifier is not currently being propagated through to the `Subject` in the `LoginModule`, but now I need it in order to log service requests.

I see two ways forward with making the account identifier available via the `Subject`, but I am uncertain which is the best practice for JAAS:

1. Extend my current "User" `Principal` implementation to include an "accountIdentifier" property that is set during `LoginModule.commit()`.
2. Implement `AccountIdentifier` as a separate `Principal` that gets added to the `Subject` during the `LoginModule.commit()`.

The first option would be easiest, but that also seems like it defeats the purpose of segregating Personally Identifying Information from accounts (which is something I need to do in order to satisfy the upcoming European GDPR requirements).

Should I even be adding the "User" principal (the one that contains the e-mail address) to the Subject?

Comment: Implementing `AccountIdentifier` as a separate `Principal` associated with the same `Subject` is the mechanism implied by the JAAS API, which itself is modeled pretty directly on standard information security concepts and terminology.  When you successfully authenticate the user, you should populate the `Subject` representing them with all the associated `Principal`s that you want to be able to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There are several incompatibilities among the JAAS and Servlet specifications regarding authentication and user principles. Because of this, Spring uses a different approach to JAAS integration than Tomcat.*

*This answer documents a comprehensive method of implementing JAAS Login Modules in a way that accommodates both Tomcat and Spring.*

---

For clarity, the two options for implementing user principles is copied here from the question:

1. Extend my current "User" `Principal` implementation to include an "accountIdentifier" property that is set during `LoginModule.commit()`.
2. Implement `AccountIdentifier` as a separate `Principal` that gets added to the `Subject` during the `LoginModule.commit()`.

Option 1 has the unfortunate side affect of joining together different forms of Personally Identifiable Information, which in some environments could violate the European GDPR regulations (sessions may be serialized onto disk, and this information would go with it).

Option 2 separates out Personally Identifiable Information, but must be implemented in a way that overcomes several limitations in the Servlet Specification and Tomcat's JAAS implementation.

These limitations are described in detail below, with the bold sections summarizing the main points.

---

### `JAASRealm` requires that the backing collection(s) of a `Subject` preserve the ordering of the `Principal`s.

The [Tomcat 8.5 JAAS Realm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/realm-howto.html#JAASRealm) documentation states:

> Using [JAASRealm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/JAASRealm.html) gives the developer the ability to combine practically
>   any conceivable security realm with Tomcat's CMA.

but then goes on to state:

> Although not specified in JAAS, you should create separate classes to
>   distinguish between users and roles, extending `javax.security.Principal`
>   so that Tomcat can tell which Principals returned from your login module
>   are users and which are roles (see `org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm`).
>   Regardless, the first Principal returned is *always* treated as the user
>   Principal.

Note that the above Tomcat documentation uses the phrase *"**the** user Principal"*. Although the JAAS API recommends implementing users and roles as distinct classes extending [javax.security.Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html), this is not compatible with the Servlet Specification because [HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal--) allows only for a single Principal to be returned:

> Returns a `javax.security.Principal` object containing the name of the
>   current authenticated user. If the user has not been authenticated,
>   the method returns null.

A strict reading of the above documentation states that it should contain *"...the name of the current authenticated user"*, but in order to satisfy my original goal, I am interpreting this as *"...any name or identifier for the authenticated Subject"*. This corresponds more closely to the [com.sun.security.auth.UserPrincipal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/UserPrincipal.html) documentation (i.e., *"A user principal identified by a username or account name"*).

Due to the above limitations in Tomcat's `JAASRealm` and the Servlet Specification's `HttpServletRequest`, it is clearly important that if the account identifier is to be propagated to the request via a `ServletFilter` (which only has access to the current session, request and response), it must be contained in the first `Principal` (thus Option 1 in the original question would satisfy this requirement, or Option 2 only if it appears first and I do not need the original username). I believe all I really need is the account identifier, so I am sticking with the second option for now, where I hand an "EmailAddressPrincipal" to `MyLoginModule` and I receive an "AccountIdentifierPrincipal" back via the `Subject` (i.e., the `MyLogin.commit()` adds the "AccountIdentifierPrincipal" as the very first principal).

The `JAASRealm` documentation is actually slightly contradictory regarding the precise order of Principals, it depends on which section you're reading:

> As this Realm iterates over the Principals returned by
>   Subject.getPrincipals(), it will identify the first Principal that
>   matches the "user classes" list as the Principal for this user

vs.

> Regardless, the first Principal returned is always treated as the user
>   Principal.

---

### **The Servlet API provides no guarantees of the ordering of `Principle`s returned by a `Subject`**.

Essentially, if I were to create a `ServletFilter` that mimics what `JAASRealm` is doing, the authentication would look like this (note the iterator in particular):

```
final LoginContext loginContext = new LoginContext(MyLoginModule.JAAS_REALM, new DefaultCallbackHandler(username, password));
loginContext.login();
final Subject subject = loginContext.getSubject();
request.getSession().setAttribute("AUTH_USER_PRINCIPAL", subject.getPrincipals(AccountIdentifierPrincipal.class).iterator().next());
request.getSession().setAttribute("AUTH_ROLE_PRINCIPALS", subject.getPrincipals(MyRolePrincipal.class));
```

Unfortunately, this is in direct conflict with the constructor for [javax.security.auth.Subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html#Subject-boolean-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-), which mandates that a [java.util.Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is used as the backing collection for Principals. Additionally, the [Set.iterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator--) documentation states:

> The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is
>   an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).

The earliest access we have to the `Subject` is in the `LoginModule.initialize()` method, which is something that is unfortunately invoked somewhere in the internals of `LoginContext` (I think). This means we have no control over the exact subclass of `Set` that is used as the backing collection for `Principals`, and therefore no control over their ordering. By the time this arrives to the `ServletFilter`, it is a [SynchronizedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-), so it isn't even clear what the original class was, or whether re-ordering occurred.

This all indicates that in order for `JAASRealm` to work as expected only a single user principal can be provided. There is no interface anywhere in that middle layer that clearly establishes the order of the `Subject` `Principals`.

---

### Conclusions

**When using `JAASRealm`, only one `Principal` of the declared User type should be added to the `Subject` during `commit`.**

**When using `JAASRealm`, avoid using multiple User class names.**

Violating the above two rules may lead to undefined and/or inconsistent behavior.

---

### Solution: Use an `AuthorityGranter` for Spring, and a `ServletFilter` for non-framework Tomcat servlets

For the sake of Option 2, I'm avoiding the use of `JAASRealm` because according to all of the above documentation, it does not faithfully adhere to JAAS. This brings me back to the pure `ServletFilter` approach.

The [javax.security.auth.Subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html) contains everything needed for authorization: multiple user principals, roles and ACL groups. Unfortunately, this class is only partially serializable, which means I can't just wrap the class as a `Principal` and return it.

In order to satisfy Spring's [DefaultJaasAuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/jaas/DefaultJaasAuthenticationProvider.html), implement an [AuthorityGranter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/jaas/AuthorityGranter.html) to map `Principal`s to role names - that provides complete control over how the mapping is performed.

Since `AuthorityGranter` isn't available outside the Spring Framework, I also implemented a `ServletFilter` that uses a similar approach to map roles for my non-Spring webapp. Temporarily, I am using an `HttpServletRequestWrapper` to read the Principal and Roles from session attributes (stored in session during authentication) and override [getUserPrincipal](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html#getUserPrincipal--) and [isUserInRole](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html#isUserInRole-java.lang.String-). Ultimately, I will revisit JAASRealm to see if it contains any functionality for handling this piece, but I'm not quite there yet.